# React native plugin code use for react web

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have react native plugin code that I want to use with react web with out any changes.
Is there any easy way to do this?

I found webview but not sure if thats correct way

Comment: What kind of code you wanna use ?  if it‘s a View component you could WebView if you wanna use some utility function you can import a node package.

Or you can use Expo (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/web/) if you wanna share code between Web and App.

Comment: I have plugin for device communication like pinpad and cash drawer and this is written  in java code.
I have used same with react native but want to use for web now

Comment: Take a look at Expo Snack https://snack.expo.dev/ which allows sharing code between iOS/Android and web.

Comment: it means I can use native plugin code with react native and web both using expo??
My base code is not in react native and not in react-native-web as well, so far I can not change/rewrite  whole code to react native web

Comment: If your plugin is a pure javascript plugin you should be able to use it. If the plugin contain java or swift/objective-c you won‘t be able to use it for a website.



It‘s not totally clear to me what is your problem is, you might write a better description.